# Open a parent web application's web.config file from child WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, svc

Here is the structure of my application. I have an asp.net web application running at the root of a website. In a child directory I have `WebServices\MyWCFService\`. Outlined here:

```
\parentapp\
\parentapp\App_Data\
\parentapp\Web.config
\parentapp\other_parent_stuff
\parentapp\WebServices\
\parentapp\WebServices\MyWCFService\
\parentapp\WebServices\MyWCFService\bin\
\parentapp\WebServices\MyWCFService\bin\MyWCFService.dll
\parentapp\WebServices\MyWCFService\Web.config (WCF's .config)
\parentapp\WebServices\MyWCFService\other_wcf_stuff
```

Ultimately what I need to do is **open the root application's `web.config` to get its connection strings** so the WCF service can connect to the database info provided there. From the WCF, I can get its own `web.config`, but I need to go up to the website's root to get that `web.config`. I get the root directory by doing this:

```
string svcDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
DirectoryInfo rootDir = Directory.GetParent(svcDir).Parent.Parent;
string root = rootDir.FullName;
```

Now apperently to open the config file, you need to use the virtual path (instead of local file system path) like so:

```
VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(root, true);
WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
```

And from there, I should be able to access the connection string by calling `config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["db_name"]`.

The problem is I can never get past the config declaration where I am getting an `ArgumentOfOfRangeException`. This was expected during testing since the `root` points to my VS Projects folder at `C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects`. So I dropped a test `web.config` file in there, but I still get the exception. *On the production servers, the path would point to the parent application's root folder, which contains the config file.*

Also, keep in mind that within the WCF Service, `HttpContext.Current` is always null so I can't use its `Request` method to get the virtual path that way. Same goes for `Server.MapPath`. Any ideas? I am not opposed to going about this a different way, so long as ultimately, I can open the parent app's `web.config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the right `ConfigurationManger` method to use in this case, where a virtual path is not needed. Here is the code:

```
//web config subfolder and filename
const string WEB_CONFIG = "\\Web.config";

//open parent application's web.config file to get connection string to specific database
string svcDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
DirectoryInfo rootDir = Directory.GetParent(svcDir).Parent.Parent;
string root = rootDir.FullName;
string webconfigPath = root + WEB_CONFIG;

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = webconfigPath;
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string connectionString = "";
if (configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["db_name"].ConnectionString.Length > 0)
{
    connectionString = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["db_name"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: It's a hack that only works if the parent is also the "filesystem"-parent

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i ended up doing this:

```
    public string GetConnectionStringValueFromParent(string key)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            const string WEB_CONFIG = "\\Web.config";

            string svcDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
            DirectoryInfo rootDir = Directory.GetParent(svcDir).Parent;
            string root = rootDir.FullName;
            string webconfigPath = root + WEB_CONFIG;

            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = webconfigPath;
            Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            if (configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString.Length > 0)
            {
                value = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return value;
    }
```